# How to download a directory's content via ftp using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sftp

So, i am trying to download the contents of a directory via sftp using nodejs, and so far I am getting stuck with an error.

I am using the [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) npm package and for the most part it works pretty well as i am able to connect to the server and list the files in a particular remote directory.

Using the fastGet method to download a file also works without any hassles, and since all the methods are promise based i assumed i could easily download all the files in the directory simply enough, by doing something like:

```
let main = async () => {
    await sftp.connect(config.sftp);
    let data = await sftp.list(config.remote_dir);
    if (data.length) data.map(async x => {
        await sftp.fastGet(`${config.remote_dir}/${x.name}`, config.base_path + x.name);
    });
}
```

So it turns out the code above successfully downloads the first file, but then crashes with the following error message:

> Error: Failed to get sandbox/demo2.txt: The requested operation cannot be performed because there is a file transfer in progress.

This seems to indicate that the promise from fastGet is resolving too early as the file transfer is supposed to be over when the next element of the file list is processed.

I tried to use the more traditional get() instead but it is using streams, and it fails with a different error. After researching it seems there's been a breaking change regarding streams in node 10.x. well in my case calling get simply fails (not even downloading the first file).

Does anyone know a workaround to this? or else, another package that can download several files by sftp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, since the issue was concurrent download attempts on one client connection, i could try to manage it with one client per file download. I ended up with the following recursive function.

```
let getFromFtp = async (arr) => {
    if (arr.length == 0) return (processFiles());
    let x = arr.shift();
    conns.push(new Client());
    let idx = conns.length - 1;
    await conns[idx].connect(config.sftp.auth);
    await conns[idx]
      .fastGet(`${config.sftp.remote_dir}/${x.name}`, `${config.dl_dir}${x.name}`);
    await connections[idx].end();
    getFromFtp(arr);
};
```

Notes about this function:

- The array parameter is a list of files to download, presumably fetched using list() beforehand
- conns was declared as an empty array and is used to contain our clients.
- using array.prototype.shift(), to gradually deplete the array as we go through the file list
- the processFiles() method is fired once all the files were downloaded.
- this is just the POC version. of couse we need to add the error management to that.